# Use $location to go back using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a url to a api which shows json. I want to be able to click that json and if i press the back button/ custom button, the browser will kinowthe previous state of the url.

Im not sure how to properly use the $location attribute in angular to to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $location already does adds to browser history, so you dont need to do anything...

Comment: define what you mean by `state`. Angular routing will take care of the back button history, but contollers for previous view will be invoked again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want something very simple just try

```
$scope.backBtnClick = function() { 
    window.history.back();
};
```

Comment: hi thanks. but the thing is, im browsing an http which is in json. so when i click a json link, i want to be able to click back to the previous json.

if that was understanable

Comment: Then, for each json link you click, you push the link (or the state) into an array, then, in back button you simply do a $location.path to the last but one link in that array. You will got an "history array", you may even store the index of states so you can access back and back to the first link.